# Qt5: how to modify download speed to show 1.xx MB/s instead of 1.xxxxx MB/s?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
 ui->progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
 ui->progressBar->setMaximum(totalBytes);
 ui->progressBar->setValue(readBytes);

double speed = readBytes * 1000.0 / downloadTime.elapsed();
    QString unit;
    if (speed < 1024) {
        unit = "bytes/sec";
    } else if (speed < 1024*1024) {
        speed /= 1024;
        unit = "kB/s";
    } else {
        speed /= 1024*1024;
        unit = "MB/s";
    }

    QString spd = QString::number(speed);

    ui->progressBar->setFormat(spd+" "+unit);
```

It works like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/86bzs.png

how should i modify this code to show speed like 1.XX MB/s ?
thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the third argument of [QString::number](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstring.html#arg-20):

```
QString::number(1.6183456, 'f', 2)
// -> "1.62"
```